# Matplotlib bar-plot built in loop sometimes places bar in wrong spot

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, plot

I have written a script to build a "digital" stratigraphic profile that shows stratigraphic changes over time for a simulated place on a landscape. This script is part of a larger project, so for now I am randomly generating the elevation changes (at a yearly interval). Anyway, I'm able to generate a nice dataframe with all the stratigraphic data formatted correctly, and I want to make a plot with this data that shows how the strata change over time. Time should be on the X axis, strata thickness on the Y, and the different strata should be shown as colors. The way I thought to do this was to build a series of bar plots in a loop, and overlay them from last to first strata. So I've coded that up, and am plotting the stratum's thickness as a bar at every point in time over the simulation. Working backwards from the youngest to the oldest stratum, this actually does make the plot I'm looking for. The problem is that every so often the bars for the last year or so of the run are inexplicably put at like year 5. This seems to happen like once in every four or five times I run the script. I can't seem to find out why this is happening, and have checked everything I can think of. I clearly need another pair of eyes here, and am wondering if anyone can see why this is happening? I am attaching [an output figure that shows the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5O5YS.png). The code is below, marked where the problem seems to be presenting iself.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

############### SET UP INIT VALUES ##############
RunLength = 100 # Number of simulated "years"
initdepth = 1.5 # start with some depth (real script will read in from year 0 soildepth map)
prefix = "test2"
#################################################
#### Make some dummy erosion/deposition data ####
di = {k:np.random.normal(0.0075, 0.1, RunLength+1) for k in ["Delta"]} #random normal for elev change
di.update({y:np.arange(RunLength+1) for y in ["Year"]}) # set up column for years (0 to RunLength)
layers = pd.DataFrame(di) # make it into a dataframe
layers['Delta'][0] = 0 #set year 0 to have no change in all the columns
layers["Cumsum"] = layers.Delta.cumsum()+initdepth # calculate cumulative sum, and put it in a column in
layers.set_index('Year', inplace = True) # move the "Year" column to be the index
layers.T.to_csv("%s_CumED.csv" % prefix) # write out csv for posterity, and so we check out work
#####################################################################
### Assemble stratigraphic profile from erosion/deposition events ###
stratigraphy = pd.DataFrame({y:np.arange(RunLength+1) for y in ["Year"]}) #set up new dataframe to contain results of stratigraphic simulation
stratigraphy["Stratum0"] = initdepth # add a column for the base soil (stratum 0)
for idx, row in layers.iterrows(): # run a loop through the stratagraphic data to make "real" layers 
    if idx == 0: # Set up the pre-run soil-depth
        stratigraphy["Stratum0"][idx:RunLength+1] = initdepth # save current depth at this year for the stratum (and fill forward in time)
        old_delta = 0 # set up "old_delta" variable
        stratum = 0 # set up "stratum" variable
        currentdepth = initdepth
    else:
        currentdepth += row['Delta'] # figure out where the surface is this year
        if row['Delta'] >= 0: # Deposition happened this year...
            if old_delta >= 0: # ...and deposition happened last year too.
                stratigraphy["Stratum%s" % stratum][idx:RunLength+1] = currentdepth # continue building current stratum
            else: # ...but erosion happened last year.
                stratum += 1 # make new stratum
                stratigraphy["Stratum%s" % stratum] = 0.0 # add a column for the new stratum
                stratigraphy["Stratum%s" % stratum][idx:RunLength+1] = currentdepth # begin building new stratum
        else: # Erosion happened this year...
            for key in stratigraphy.keys(): #loop through strata
                if stratigraphy[key][idx] > currentdepth: # do we need to erode an old stratum?
                    stratigraphy[key][idx:RunLength+1] = currentdepth #erode!
        old_delta = row["Delta"]
##################################################################
### Make a plot showing how the stratigraphy changes over time ###
plt.ioff() # explicitly set interactive plotting off
sns.set_style("ticks") # set plot style with seaborn
sns.set_context("poster", font_scale = 1.1)
colors = sns.cubehelix_palette(stratum + 1, start=.75, rot=1.5, dark=.25) # grab nice cube helix color palette
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(17, 8)) #make blank plot with wide aspect ratio
ax.set_autoscale_on(False) # not sure if this doesn anything
### PROBLEM SEEMS TO BE HAPPENING IN HERE
for strat in reversed(range(stratum+1)): # loop through the strata, and overlay them on the plot
    ax.bar(stratigraphy.Year, stratigraphy.ix[:,strat+1], width=1, linewidth=0, color=colors[strat], label="Stratum %s" % strat) # this makes a new overlay for each strata across the years
### /PROBLEM    
ax.plot(layers.Delta.cumsum()+initdepth, color='black', drawstyle="steps-post") # plot a line of where the ground surface has been over time
ax.plot((0, np.amax(stratigraphy.Year)), (np.amax(stratigraphy.ix[:,stratum + 1]), np.amax(stratigraphy.ix[:,stratum + 1])), color='grey', linestyle='dashed') # plot a horizontal line for modern day surface
ax.set_xlim(0,np.amax(stratigraphy.Year)+2) # set limit of X axis a little larger to show last value
ax.set_ylim(0,np.amax(np.amax(stratigraphy.ix[:,1:stratigraphy.shape[1]]))) # set y axis range to match data range
ax.locator_params(nbins = 8) # set tick interval
plt.xlabel('Year')
plt.ylabel('Thickness of stratigraphic layers (m)')
ax.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.015, 0.5), fontsize='small', frameon='True', shadow='True', fancybox='True') # put legend of to right of the plot area
fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.065, right=0.90) #tighten up the layout
sns.despine(fig) # remove extraneous plot ticks
plt.savefig("%s_stratigraphy_stackedbar.png" % prefix, dpi=300) # save plot to file
plt.close()
```

EDIT: adding minimal example, below. Here's a [link to a sample CSV file to use it with.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dk2tnpuol54kqzp/stratigraphy.csv?dl=0)

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
stratigraphy = pd.read_csv('stratigraphy.csv')
plt.ioff() # explicitly set interactive plotting off
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(17, 8)) #make blank plot with wide aspect ratio
### PROBLEM SEEMS TO BE HAPPENING IN HERE
for strat in reversed(range(stratum+1)): # loop through the strata, and overlay them on the plot
    ax.bar(stratigraphy.Year, stratigraphy.ix[:,strat+1], width=1, linewidth=0, color=colors[strat], label="Stratum %s" % strat) # this makes a new overlay for each strata across the years
### /PROBLEM    
ax.set_xlim(0,np.amax(stratigraphy.Year)+2) # set limit of x axis
ax.set_ylim(0,np.amax(np.amax(stratigraphy.ix[:,1:stratigraphy.shape[1]]))) # set y axis range to match data range
plt.xlabel('Year')
plt.ylabel('Thickness of stratigraphic layers (m)')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you post a **minimal** example? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Sure thing. Added it now. Thanks for your interest!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your CSV file I can see that there's no year (I assume, first row) 200, but instead a value 1.326197, which would mean that the last column of data will be plotted somewhere in the beginning. Size and position match the offset bar on your graph. I don't know why you would occasionally see it, and then not, but please make sure that your generating data properly. Surprising for me is that you have 201 columns. Since Python counts from zero I would assume that the number would be multiplication of 100.

Comment: Huh! I did not notice that! I will check the first part of the full script where I am generating that data and see where/how it could occasionally be messing that up. I have 201 columns because I added an extra column for the year.

Comment: That was definitely the clue I needed!! The problem was due to that extra column I was inserting for the year. I moved to be the index before running through the loop that accumulates the stratigraphy, and it all works well (with adjustments for new ranges, etc.). Thank you!!